# In cxvpy, Is that possible to constraint ((x==0) or (1<= x <=2))

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

Suppose I have an objective y=f(x), I want to Maximinze y subject to (x==0) or (1 <= x <= 2).
How to describe the problem in Python code using cvxpy. For example, the following code Max y subject to x in [1, 2] without the feasible domain x==0

````
import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable((2,1))
alpha = np.array([-1,1]).reshape(1,-1)
y = alpha @ x
constraint = [x <= 2, x >= 1]
obj = cp.Maximize(y)
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraint)```

prob.solve()
print("optimal", prob.value)
print("solution", x.value.ravel())
````

Output

```
optimal 1.0
solution [1.0 2.0]
```

Is that possible to modify the constraint to make x feasible in ((x==0) or (1 <= x <= 2))？
The pseudocode may be：

```
constraint = [x <= 2, x >= 1] or [x == 0]
```

and then the expected output will be

```
optimal 2.0
solution [0.0 2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **semi-continuous variable**. Most solvers/tools have direct support for this, but CVXPY is not one of them. You need to model this with an extra binary variable:

```
  δ ≤ x ≤ 2δ 
  δ ∈ {0,1}
  x ∈ [0,2]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to chain constraints together like `((x==0) or (1<= x <=2))`. This is what the documentation states:

> you cannot chain constraints together, e.g., 0 <= x <= 1 or x == y ==
> 2. The Python interpreter treats chained constraints in such a way that CVXPY cannot capture them. CVXPY will raise an exception if you
> write a chained constraint.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#constraints).